# JavaFX 8 : Class spinner does not want to instantiate

Tags: windows, javafx-8

I test my application (JavaFX Application with embedded JDK 8 : 8u66 ea-b02) on multiple system configurations (Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10).

In tests on three PC with **Windows 7 64 bit**, I encountered a very strange problem.

**My application works correctly on the 2 PC, not on the third !**

After tracing the problem (on the third PC), the application stops running when i try to instantiate my customized Spinner class.

I have no logs ! the application stops and exits immediately.

This is the instantiation of my class (based on the builder pattern) :

```
CustomSpinner defaultSpinner1 = new CustomSpinner.CustomSpinnerBuilder(
                "[Compteur]", 1, CustomSpinner.MAX_VALUE).titleWidth(110)
                .height(30).build();
```

and the declaration of my CustomSpinner class :

```
public class CustomSpinner extends javafx.scene.control.Spinner<Integer> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomSpinner.class);

    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 999999;

    private String title; // obligatoire

    private int minValue; // obligatoire

    private int maxValue; // obligatoire

    private int titleWidth; // optionnel

    private int width; // optionnel

    private LocalTime previousTime;

    private LocalTime previousTimeBS;

    private LocalTime previousTimeD;

    private double height; // optionnel

    public CustomSpinner(CustomSpinnerBuilder builder) {
        super();

        previousTime = null;
        previousTimeBS = null;
        previousTimeD = null;

        title = builder.title;
        minValue = builder.minValue;
        maxValue = builder.maxValue;

        titleWidth = builder.titleWidth;
        width = builder.width;
        height = builder.height;

        this.setMinWidth(width);
        this.setMaxWidth(width);
        this.setPrefWidth(width);

        this.setMinHeight(height);
        this.setMaxHeight(height);
        this.setPrefHeight(height);

        this.setValueFactory(new javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(
                minValue, maxValue));

        this.setEditable(true);

        DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();

        ds.setOffsetY(3.0);
        ds.setOffsetX(3.0);
        ds.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        this.setEffect(ds);

        // filtre numérique
        this.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (!(event.getCharacter().charAt(0) >= '0' && event
                        .getCharacter().charAt(0) <= '9'))
                    event.consume();
                else {
                    // utilisé pour contourner bug lorsqu'on utilise d'abord les
                    // arrows + saisie dans zone -> la valeur saisie est doublée
                    // solution : il faut au moins 1 seconde entre 2 appels de
                    // handle()
                    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();

                    if (previousTime == null
                            || currentTime.toSecondOfDay() != previousTime
                                    .toSecondOfDay()) {
                        // prise en compte valeur saisie
                        javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = getValueFactory();

                        String cpt = valueFactory.getValue().toString()
                                + event.getCharacter().charAt(0);

                        event.consume();

                        valueFactory.setValue(Integer.parseInt(cpt));

                        // positionner le curseur à la dernière position de la
                        // zone
                        getEditor().positionCaret(
                                valueFactory.getValue().toString().length());

                        previousTime = currentTime;
                    } else
                        event.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        // touches DELETE, BACKSPACE
        this.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
                    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();

                    if (previousTimeD != null)
                        logger.debug("delete = " + currentTime.toSecondOfDay()
                                + " " + previousTimeD.toSecondOfDay());
                    else
                        logger.debug("delete = " + currentTime.toSecondOfDay());

                    if (previousTimeD == null
                            || currentTime.toSecondOfDay() != previousTimeD
                                    .toSecondOfDay()) {
                        // supprimer caractère
                        int pCaret = getEditor().caretPositionProperty()
                                .intValue();

                        javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = getValueFactory();

                        String newCpt = null;

                        try {
                            newCpt = valueFactory.getValue().toString()
                                    .substring(0, pCaret)
                                    + valueFactory.getValue().toString()
                                            .substring(pCaret + 1);
                        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                            newCpt = valueFactory.getValue().toString()
                                    .substring(0, pCaret);
                        }

                        if (newCpt.equals(""))
                            newCpt = minValue + "";

                        if (Integer.parseInt(newCpt) > maxValue)
                            newCpt = maxValue + "";

                        valueFactory.setValue(Integer.parseInt(newCpt));

                        event.consume();

                        // positionner le curseur
                        getEditor().positionCaret(pCaret);

                        previousTimeD = currentTime;
                    } else
                        event.consume();
                }

                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
                    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();

                    if (previousTimeBS != null)
                        logger.debug("backspace = "
                                + currentTime.toSecondOfDay() + " "
                                + previousTimeBS.toSecondOfDay());
                    else
                        logger.debug("backspace = "
                                + currentTime.toSecondOfDay());

                    if (previousTimeBS == null
                            || currentTime.toSecondOfDay() != previousTimeBS
                                    .toSecondOfDay()) {
                        // supprimer caractère
                        int pCaret = getEditor().caretPositionProperty()
                                .intValue();

                        if ((pCaret - 1) < 0)
                            pCaret = 0;
                        else
                            pCaret--;

                        javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = getValueFactory();

                        String newCpt = valueFactory.getValue().toString()
                                .substring(0, pCaret)
                                + valueFactory
                                        .getValue()
                                        .toString()
                                        .substring(
                                                getEditor()
                                                        .caretPositionProperty()
                                                        .intValue());

                        if (newCpt.equals(""))
                            newCpt = minValue + "";

                        if (Integer.parseInt(newCpt) > maxValue)
                            newCpt = maxValue + "";

                        valueFactory.setValue(Integer.parseInt(newCpt));

                        event.consume();

                        // positionner le curseur
                        getEditor().positionCaret(pCaret);

                        previousTimeBS = currentTime;
                    } else
                        event.consume();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class CustomSpinnerBuilder {
        private String title; // obligatoire

        private int minValue = 1; // obligatoire

        private int maxValue = MAX_VALUE; // obligatoire

        private int titleWidth = 100; // optionnel

        private int width = 110; // optionnel

        private double height = TextField.USE_PREF_SIZE; // optionnel

        public CustomSpinnerBuilder(String title, int minValue, int maxValue) {
            this.title = title;
            this.minValue = minValue;
            this.maxValue = maxValue;
        }

        public CustomSpinnerBuilder height(double height) {
            this.height = height;

            return this;
        }

        public CustomSpinnerBuilder titleWidth(int width) {
            this.titleWidth = width;

            return this;
        }

        public CustomSpinnerBuilder width(int width) {
            this.width = width;

            return this;
        }

        public CustomSpinner build() {
            return new CustomSpinner(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas for this strange behavior ?

What are the reasons why a class is not instantiated when running (in my case for a JavaFX application) ?

Is it possible to get system logs (to try to understand the source of the problem) ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Spinner class is added to JavaFX with the update "8u40". If the version of JavaFX installed on your device is older than this, your IDE will not recognize Spinner class in JavaFX. In that case, you need to update your JDK.

Comment: the JDK embedded in my JavaFX application is 8u66 JDK, so no problem !

Comment: the advantage of having an embedded JDK, it is not dependent on any JRE installed on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In fact i had two versions of my application installed on this PC.

I forgot to uninstall the old version (very old version !). This old version was embedded with JDK 8u20 (< 8u40 for Spinner Class).

I think there was a confuse system behavior between both applications (with two different version of JDK).

So, i uninstalled the old version then i installed the new version : it's ok !